# Xamarin.Forms - Is it possible to reference a tabbedpage, in a contentpage

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Fairly new to xamarin.forms.

I have a question regarding the tabbedpage.

Is it possible to reference it in a contentpage, like shown in the simple drawing?

[image: Tabbedpage]

I've searched a lot, but cant really find anything about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not with the standard TabbedPage control.  There are numerous 3rd party TabView controls (commercial and open source) that will do this

Comment: @Jason Do you have any experience with one of them? Some you can 
recommend? 

Comment: In your case you could use CarouselView https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/ Or install the plugin TabView (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.TabView/) from nuget .